# Dependency injection using go interface

Tags: go, dependency-injection, interface

Im trying to use some dependency injection via go interface after reading some docs about it.

I’ve two methods which should implement one interface

```
type Shooter interface {
    Spec(ev v1alpha1.Ev) (v1beta1.Shoot, error)
}

type Project struct {
    Name string
}
```

https://github.com/JennyMet/testint/blob/master/internal/infra/common.go#L8

The concrete implementation is here
https://github.com/JennyMet/testint/blob/master/internal/infra/azure/azure.go#L13
https://github.com/JennyMet/testint/blob/master/internal/infra/gcp/gcp.go#L13

e.g.

```
func (n Project) Spec(ev v1alpha1.Ev) (v1beta1.Shoot, error) {
    var shoot = v1beta1.Shoot{}
    fmt.Println(shoot, ev)
    return shoot, nil
}
```

Now I want to get the specific implementation in package above and I tried the following

https://github.com/JennyMet/testint/blob/master/internal/infra/provider.go#L16

```
func kind(ev v1alpha1.Ev, namespace string) (v1beta1.Shoot, error) {
    var shoot v1beta1.Shoot
    var e error
    switch ev.Spec.Infrastructure.Type {
    case "gcp":
        project := gcp.Project{Name: namespace}
        shoot, e = project.Spec(ev)
        if e != nil {
            return v1beta1.Shoot{}, e
        }
```

But it doesn’t works, any ideas how can I do it right?

Comment: May you rephrase your question ? There is some mixed up terminology here.

Do you want to know what structure implements an interface ?

Comment: @AdoRen - no , I want to use the implementations of `spec` inside the provider.go file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it doesn’t works

It is not specified, but I assume that Dependency Injection does not work.

Injection requires at least two different entity types. One is injected and the second on is a target receiving that injection.

In your case, you have only one - Injection implemented in two forms `gcp` and `azure`.

You need to add a target that contains injected interface:

```
type Target struct {
    Specer Shooter
}

func (t *Target) DoWork() {
   // here you can use t.Specer.Spec() without knowing implementation details
}
```

Now you can create `Target` using DI:

```
func NewTarget(specer Shooter) *Target{
        return &Target{
          Specer: specer,
        } 
}
```

Your code typically decides on all used types and injects them (calling `NewTarget()`) very close to application start in [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/)

Update:

Interface is also can be injected into function. It is also Dependency Injection:

```
func kind(ev v1alpha1.Ev, namespace string, specer Shooter) (v1beta1.Shoot, error) {
   ...
   shoot, e = specer.Spec(ev)
   ...
}
```

That is an alternative to a pattern called Service Locator:

```
func kind(ev v1alpha1.Ev, namespace string) (v1beta1.Shoot, error) {
   ...
   specer := factory.GetSpecer()
   shoot, e = specer.Spec(ev)
   ...
}
```

Service Locator often referred as antipattern.

Comment: Thanks, the target should be used here ? https://github.com/JennyMet/testint/blob/master/internal/infra/provider.go#L16

Comment: another question, for best practice where should I declere the interface and the types you refer ?

Comment: You need to separate dependency instantiation and using in code. `kind` does these two things together. That should be split.

Comment: regard this, `func kind(ev v1alpha1.Ev, namespace string, specer Shooter) (v1beta1.Shoot, error) {
   ...
   shoot, e = specer.Spec(ev)
   ...
}` where you should put the concrete implementation ?

Comment: Decide what is `kind` responsibility - doing work  (this is work - `shoot, e = project.Spec(ev)`) or managing dependensies.

Comment: the biggest issue here is how to remove this deps from the file `https://github.com/JennyMet/testint/blob/master/internal/infra/provider.go#L7-L8` it will be great if you can provide an example what is the best way to use it in https://github.com/JennyMet/testint/blob/master/internal/infra/provider.go#L16